# How to add password prompt when clicking on excel tab

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I need to have a password prompt when someone clicks on a specific tab in an excel workbook. I know how to add a password prompt when opening the file as a whole, but not an individual tab. I figured this would have been a simple Google search, but couldn't find anything useful.. Any help would be appreciated!

**Side note: The key with what I need to do is it needs to be a PROMPTED password, not a protected sheet password where someone would have to right click the tab and click 'unprotect sheet'. The people that will be using this workbook will not know how to unprotect a sheet like that, so it must be a prompt for them to just type it in when clicking on the tab.

Comment: You could use a protect sheet password, in combination with a VBA form to prompt for the password.

Comment: You will probably need vba in a worksheet_activate event.

Comment: Just FYI - just about any password you add, via VBA or the built-in password protection, can be relatively easily broken by a decently competent user (or a user who can Google).

Comment: @BruceWayne I was thinking the same, but am making the assumption that if they do not know how to right click and unprotect sheet, he should be relatively safe from this, probably shouldn't assume though.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work.. any recommendations on what to change?:
Sub password() 
    Dim pass As String 
    pass = InputBox("Enter Password") 
    If pass <> "thepassword" Then Exit Sub 
End Sub

Comment: How would I implement that code in an activate event? Sorry, I'm still somewhat new to VB/VBA

Comment: Look into [`Worksheet_Activate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198220.aspx) or [`Worksheet_Change`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) events.  The examples on those links should help you see how to run. Essentailly, instead of starting it with `Sub myMacro` it's `Sub Worksheet_Change()`

Comment: That worked, thank you all so much for your help!!